# CASE WHEN expression in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, case

I have two tables "prods"(id, price) and "prods_prices"(id, prod_id, price). It is necessary to display "prods". The minimum price for each product from prods_prices, and if there is none, then 'prods'.'price'.
I did it but I think it's wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "prods"."id" as "id", "prods"."price",
CASE
    WHEN (SELECT min("prods_prices"."price") FROM "prods_prices"  WHERE "prods_prices"."prod_id"=id) isnull THEN "prods"."price"
    ELSE (SELECT min("prods_prices"."price") FROM "prods_prices"  WHERE "prods_prices"."prod_id"=id)
  END 
  AS "price",
FROM "prods"
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add create script, sample datas and expected result

Comment: It's `is null`, not `isnull`.

Comment: You have two columns named `price` in your result. That might confuse the database client you are using.

Answer (score 2):

If `id` is the primary key on `prods`, then:

```
select   prods.id, 
         coalesce(min(prods_prices.price), prods.price) price
from     prods 
left join prods_prices on prods_prices.prod_id = prods.id
group by prods.id
```

`Coalesce` returns `prods.price` if `min(prods_prices.price)` is null.

Comment: If i am not mistaken, It should not be possible to use prods.price in coalesce function.

Comment: @boran Can you explain why? I can't think of a reason ... an expression ought to be fine there.

Comment: Here, i pasted the query to above dbfiddle, maybe you have a different schema in your mind, the question is not exactly clear. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7seKV4MsYPnNmDH5rdMzt8/1

Comment: Ah yes, that was because prods.id was not declared to be a primary key, so prods.price had to be included in the group by. With id as the primary key on prods the PostgreSQL optimiser recognises that prods.price is not required in the group by, and the query is valid

Comment: wow I had no idea about this, thx for explaining

Comment: I think that Oracle does not do this - I was very pleased to learn that PG does 

Answer (score 0):

With the few informations you gave, you can do the next query ([Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7seKV4MsYPnNmDH5rdMzt8/0))

```
with min_price as (select prod_id,min(price) as price from prod_prices group by prod_id)
select p.id,case when mp is null then p.price else mp.price end as price
from prods p left join min_price mp on p.id = mp.prod_id
```